# how to merge two data frame by rows of x and y but columns should be side (df1$x) by side (df2$y)?

Tags: r, dplyr, multidplyr

I have two dataframes with same name of columns and rows. I would like to merge them by rows but columns need to be side by side as of df$x and df$y.

**I tried so far but not getting output as required.**

```
merge(df.test1, df.test2, by.x = "V1", by.y = "V1")
```

**Output**

```
    V1  2800M_15-0.5-1.x    2800M_15-0.5-2.x    2800M_15-0.5-3.x    cA_15-0.5-1.x   cA_15-0.5-2.x   2800M_15-0.5-1.y    2800M_15-0.5-2.y    2800M_15-0.5-3.y    cA_15-0.5-1.y   cA_15-0.5-2.y
1   RowA    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   RowB    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3   RowC    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

**Required Output**

```
    V1  2800M_15-0.5-1.x    2800M_15-0.5-1.y    2800M_15-0.5-2.x    2800M_15-0.5-2.y    2800M_15-0.5-3.x    2800M_15-0.5-3.y    cA_15-0.5-1.x   cA_15-0.5-1.y   cA_15-0.5-2.x   cA_15-0.5-2.y
1   RowA    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   RowB    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3   RowC    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to reorder the columns based  on the names i.e. `order` on the substring of column names without the `.x` or `.y` at the end, and use the order index as column indexing for rearranging the columns

```
out <- merge(df.test1, df.test2, by.x = "V1", by.y = "V1")
out1 <- out[c(1, order(sub("\\.[xy]$", "", names(out)[-1])) + 1)]
```

Comment: Awesome Akrun, why i wouldn’t  think of it. I will accept the ans in 9 min as per stackoverflow condition. LOL
Thanks though.